# Reflecting on executing assembly

Tags: c#, linq, assemblies

I have the following linq statement

```
builtIn = (from type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
where type.IsClass && type.Namespace.ToUpper().StartsWith("PD3.MODULES.BUILTIN.")
let onStartMethod = type.GetMethod("Init")
where onStartMethod != null
select onStartMethod
);
```

but it only works if I leave out the

`&& type.Namespace.ToUpper().StartsWith("PD3.MODULES.BUILTIN")` part :(

Further down the code, I have to take this into account using

```
if (builtInInit.ToString() == "Pd3.Module Init()")
```

but I really don't like this solution so here's my 2 part question

1. Is there a better way of getting methods where the namespace condition is correct?
   and
2. Why do the type.Namespace fail?

With Regard,
Stig

Comment: Why isn't it working? Throwing an exception? Returning no elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Types in the root namespace can have a null namespace, so it is calling `.StartsWith` on a null; just eliminate those first:

```
... && type.Namespace != null && type.Namespace. {blah}
```